# Why do sampling designs with variable sample size suffer from greater variance of the HT estimator?

Tags: survey-sampling

I am following the reference *Model Assisted Survey Sampling* by Särndal. In chapter 3 we are introduced to the Bernoulli sampling and calculate the Horvitz-Thompson for the population total $Y_U$ of some variable $y$. If $U = \{1,\dots,N\}$ is the population, $\pi$ the probability of inclusion, and $s$ the sample, the HT estimator takes the form
$$\widehat {Y}_U = \frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{k\in s}y_k$$
and its variance is
$$V_{Brs}(\widehat {Y}_U)= \left(\frac{1}{\pi}-1\right)\sum_{k\in U}y_k^2$$
Later, an alternative estimator is introduced
$$\widehat {Y}^{\ alt}_U = \frac{N}{n_s}\sum_{k\in s}y_k$$
and we are told that the sample size $n_s$ is included to counter the variability that stems form the sample size variation. In fact, comparison of the variances suggests that the new estimator is more accurate.

I want to confirm that there is nothing on the HT estimator, its expression or its variance, that suggests that the variability of sample size is going to play against it in terms of a large variance. That it is only through comparison with the alternative estimator that we infer the effect of variable sample size. It is my impresion that we would purposefully include the sample size in the denominator to test this hypothesis, guided maybe by previous experiments.

Comment: What is the expectation of the new estimator?

Comment: This is not entirely clear to me. Are you simply looking for an intuitive explanation of why variability of weights increases variance?